# Export Distribution Group Members, include forwardingsmtpaddress

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Is there a way I can export Distribution group members but also get the forwardingsmtpaddress included?

Right now I'm using two exports and having to setup vlookup in order to get forwarding addresses.

Here is the command I'm using to export the members I want.

```
Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "groupname@domain.com"  | Sort -Property EmailAddress | Export-Csv –Path C:\admin\groupname.csv
```

Here's the command I use to export the forwarding addresses:

```
get-mailbox | select UserPrincipalName,ForwardingAddress,ForwardingSmtpAddress,DeliverToMailboxAndForward | Export-Csv –Path C:\admin\Forwardingemails.csv
```

The "get-distributiongroupmember" command pulls in a ton of info but nothing on my members forwarding addresses.

Comment: What properties do you want to export from `Get-DistributionGroupMember`?

Comment: Forwardingsmtpaddress